# Order and type of an entire function $f$ such that the numbers $f^{(n)}(0)$ are integers.

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics

Let $f$ be an entire function with order $p=1$ and such that the numbers $f^{(n)}(0)$ are integers. Then show that the type $\sigma$ is at least $1$.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I imagine  you meant *$f^{(n)}(0)$ is an integer, for all $n\in\mathbb N$.* What is the meaning of *type $\sigma$* ?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function#Order_and_type

Comment: @ronno Note $a_n = f^{(n)}(0)/n!$.  Also, $f(z) = e^z$ is an example of a function with $\sigma = 1$.

Comment: I went ahead and edited your question with $f^{(n)}(0)$ instead of $f^n(0)$. If this is not what you meant, sorry (and I'll delete my answer...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its order $\rho$ is $1$, then $f$ can not be a polynomial and there are infinitely many $n$'s for which $f^{(n)}(0)\neq 0$. If the latter are assumed to be integers, we get a subsequence $n_k$ such that 
$$
|f^{(n_k)}(0)|\geq 1 \qquad \forall k
$$

Now denote $M(r)$ the maximum of $|f|$ on the disk of radius $r$ centered at $0$. It follows from  [Cauchy's integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem) that
$$
|f^{(n)}(0)|\leq \frac{n! M(r)}{2\pi r^n} \qquad \forall r>0\quad \forall n
$$
In particular, we see that for $r=n=n_k$, we have
$$
M(n_k)\geq \frac{2\pi n_k^{n_k}}{n_k!}\quad\Rightarrow \quad \frac{\ln M(n_k)}{n_k}\geq \frac{\ln (2\pi)}{n_k}+ \frac{1}{n_k}\ln \left( \frac{n_k^{n_k}}{n_k!}\right)\qquad \forall k
$$
By [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), the limit of the rhs is $1$. Therefore, it follows readily from the [definition of the type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function#Order_and_type) $\sigma$ of an order $\rho=1$ entire function that
$$
\sigma =\limsup_{r\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\ln M(r)}{r^\rho}\geq \limsup_{k\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\ln M(n_k)}{n_k}\geq \lim_{k\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\ln (2\pi)}{n_k}+ \frac{1}{n_k}\ln \left( \frac{n_k^{n_k}}{n_k!}\right)=1
$$

---

Remains of a huge overkill...

**Preliminary facts**   As noted by Stephen Montgomery-Smith, recall that the MacLaurin series expansion of an entire function  $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ is given by $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$.

The order $\rho $ of $f$ satisfies ([Theorem 9.4 p.257](http://books.google.ca/books?id=DYCOCBCBwoIC&lpg=PP1&hl=fr&pg=PA257#v=onepage&q&f=false))
$$
\rho =\limsup_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{n\ln n}{-\ln |a_n|}
$$

> and its type $\sigma $ obeys ([Theorem 9.5 p.259](http://books.google.ca/books?id=DYCOCBCBwoIC&lpg=PP1&hl=fr&pg=PA259#v=onepage&q&f=false))
>   $$
> \sigma =\frac{1}{e\rho } \limsup_{n\rightarrow +\infty}n|a_n|^\frac{\rho}{n}
> $$

It follows that 
$$
(\rho \sigma)^\frac{1}{\rho}=e^{1-\frac{1}{\rho}}\limsup_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{|f^{(n)}(0)|}{n^{1-\frac{1}{\rho}}}
$$
where the derivatives could actually be taken at any $z_0$.

**Solution**   If $\rho=1$, then $f$ can not be a polynomial and there are infinitely many $n$'s for which $f^{(n)}(0)\neq 0$. If the latter are assumed to be integers, we get a subsequence $n_k$ such that 
$$
|f^{(n_k)}(0)|\geq 1 \qquad \forall k
$$
Plugging this in the second formula above and using Stirling's formula yields
$$
\sigma \geq \frac{1}{e} \lim_{k\rightarrow +\infty} n_k \cdot (n_k!)^{-\frac{1}{n_k}}=\frac{1}{e} \lim_{k\rightarrow +\infty} n_k\cdot \left(\left(\frac{n_k}{e}\right)^{n_k}\sqrt{2\pi n_k}\right)^{-\frac{1}{n_k}}=1.
$$
Or, plugging this in the third formula above gives $\sigma \geq 1$ directly. $\Box$